# Mayavi view current camera settings

Tags: python, mayavi

I would like to be able to set the view of my mayavi plot to a view that I have set in the interactive window. The view can be set with the [`mlab.view`](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_camera.html) interface. However, I can't seem to find the view parameters from within the mayavi interactive GUI.

When viewing a plot in interactive mode in `matplotlib`, the camera angle and azimuth are displayed in the bottom of the screen as seen here:

[image]

This is convenient, because to replicate a view I like, I can just read off the elevation and azimuth and set them in my code (in this case with `ax.view_init(elev=-9, azim=84)`. I would like to do the same in `mayavi`. Given this code example:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
    
img = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(512, 512)).astype(np.int)

N = 10000
event_size = 2
xs = np.random.uniform(img.shape[1], size=N)
ys = np.random.uniform(img.shape[0], size=N)
ts = np.sort(np.random.uniform(1000, size=N))
ps = np.random.randint(0,2,size=N)

mlab.imshow(img, colormap='gray', extent=[0, img.shape[0], 0, img.shape[1], ts[0], ts[1]])
colors = [0 if p>0 else 240 for p in ps]
ones = np.ones(len(xs))
p3d = mlab.quiver3d(ys, xs, ts, ones, ones,
            ones, scalars=colors, mode='sphere', scale_factor=event_size)
p3d.glyph.color_mode = 'color_by_scalar'

p3d.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table = colors
mlab.draw()
mlab.show()
```

This code should create an image and a point cloud and display it in an interactive window. Where in the window can I tell what the current camera parameters are and how would I apply them in the code?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found in the documentation was to use the [`mayavi` record feature](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/application.html#recording-mayavi-actions-to-a-script) in the UI. This will log all actions to a python executable script, which will print the camera positions you place the scene in.

Alternatively, when in the `mayavi` UI, one can type python commands in the UI terminal, so entering

```
from mayavi import mlab
print(mlab.view())
```

will also give the camera params.